# Workarounds for massive performance penalty for DISTINCT on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

when I send the following query to our db, it returns 4636 rows in < 2 seconds:

```
select
    company3_.Un_ID as col_0_0_ 
from
    MNT_Equipments equip
inner join
    DynamicProperties dprops
        on equip.propertiesId=dprops.id
inner join
    DynamicPropertiesValue dvalues
        on dprops.id=dvalues.dynamicPropertiesId
inner join
    Companies company3_
        on dvalues.companyId=COMPANY.Un_ID
where
    equip.discriminator='9000'
    and equip.active=1
    and dvalues.propertyName='Eigentuemer'
```

But when I add a distinct to the select clause, it takes almost 4.5 minutes to return the remaining 40 entries. This seems to be somewhat out of proportion - what can I do to improve this, work around it or at least find out, what exactly is happening here?

Execution plans

**No Distinct**

[image: Plan 1]

**With Distinct**

[image: Plan 2]

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Please upload the execution plans with & without distinct to an external site - imgur.com for example. Or perhaps upload the XML plans somewhere where we can see them.

Comment: [Here's the album](http://imgur.com/a/W8VfL)

Comment: is maybe a grouping clause a better option, since you're selecting only one column?

Comment: [Here's the execution plan for the query without distinct](http://i.imgur.com/BTGZa.jpg)

Comment: [Here's the execution plan for the query with distinct](http://i.imgur.com/fFekKh.jpg)

Comment: Those are the actual execution plans (if that makes any duifference).

Comment: Check that you have auto update and auto create statistics turned on. That clustered index scan on the inside of the nested loops join looks very dodgy. If you select the bottom CI scan in the `DISTINCT` version and look in the properties window what is the actual vs estimated number of executions?

Comment: @RiverC: Nope, doesn't change a thing. Even the Execution Plan is still the same.

Comment: @Martin Smith: There is quite a discrepancy: estimated Number of rows (which I hope is what you asked for):5564,32 vs actual number of rows: 99259278

Comment: @Myles_TR - If you right click that clustered index scan in the actual execution plan and choose properties the properties windows should come up. What is the value for "Number of Executions" and "Estimated Number of Executions"? (or alternatively might be better to tell us actual vs estimated rows for every arrow in the plan?) Also as well as possible statistics issue it looks like you have no useful indexes either for the join or the `WHERE` clause BTW.

Comment: @Martin Smith: you're right, there are no indexes on the tables at all.
About the "Number od Executions": The properties window does not I can't find these values in my properties window. I'll make screenshots to give you all the info I have.

Comment: @Myles_TR - If you mouse over the arrows can you just take a note of the actual vs estimated number of rows and say what they all are then? There's only 7 of them.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I've created a new Album containing the properties for the CI and for all the arrows [here](http://imgur.com/a/PVcwN).

Comment: The query in your question has 4 tables but only 3 are shown in the plan. Are you running that actual query? If not can you please update it?

Comment: I'm running that exact query. Would it help you if I posted the properties for all the nodes in the execution plan, too?

Comment: Which is the table in the screenshot beginning with `D`? Is it `DynamicProperties` or `DynamicPropertiesValue`? I presume it must be the Value one and it misses out the other as there is a FK on it.

Comment: Also how many rows in total are there in both `DynamicPropertiesValue` and `Companies`? Trying to see where the one row estimate is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clustered index scans indicate that there are no good indexes on the queried tables.
If you create the following indexes the execution times should improve.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MNT_Equipments_Active] ON [MNT_Equipments] 
(
    [propertiesId] ASC,
    [discriminator] ASC,
    [active] ASC
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DynamicPropertiesValue_Name] ON [DynamicPropertiesValue] 
(
    [propertyName] ASC
)
GO
```

Comment: As a general point this is true and it might happen to cause a new plan to be generated that avoids the issue but the same applies to the query without `DISTINCT` too. There is a cardinality estimation issue.

Comment: Without indexes SQL server makes a guess, based on the expected returned rows of a subquery, what the best query plan is and in this case the query plan for the distinct is very bad. Creating indexes will help SQL server make a better decision.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that the OP does not need additional indexes, but they still may get a sub optimal plan as it doesn't get to the bottom of why the estimate for the join is so wrong.

Comment: Wow, That's spectacular - now the query ran in < 1second.